# Drupal node.save and JSONP

Tags: drupal, jsonp, drupal-services, drupal-modules

I am having an issue with call Drupal node.save using MooTool's JSONP. Here is an example.

Here is my request:

callback Request.JSONP.request_map.request_1
method node.save
sessid 123123123123123
node {"type":"blog","title":"New Title","body":"This is the blog body"}

Here is my result

HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error

I got this working before, but i used AMFPHP and was able to send objects to drupal. I am assuming that this has to do with Drupal expecting an object, but since it is a GET it gets transformed as a string. Is there any way of getting around this with out hacking the code?

Here is my code:

```
$('newBlogSubmit').addEvent('click', function()
{
    var node = {
        type : "blog",
        title:"New Title",
        body :"This is the blog body"
    }

    var string = JSON.encode(node);
    string.escapeRegExp()

    var sessID = _sessID;

    DrupalService.getInstance().node_save(string, sessID, drupal_handleBlogSubmit);
});
```

My Drupal Service JS Code:

```
//NODE
DrupalService.prototype.node_save = function(node, sessid, callback){
    var dataObj = {
        method : "node.save",
        sessid : sessid,
        node : node
    }
    DrupalService.getInstance().request(dataObj, callback);
}


//SEND REQUEST AND CALLBACK FUNCTION

DrupalService.prototype.request = function(dataObject, callback){
    new JsonP('http://myDrupalSite.com/services/json', {data: dataObject,onComplete: callback}).request();
}
```

I am trying to connect the dots, but not too familiar with Drupal, but i would guess all I need to do is turn the string back into an object. Any ideas where I should be looking, or if there is an existing patch?

Answer (score 0):

A first question could be why you use mootools since Drupal comes with jQuery and use it extensively throughout the different modules and Drupal core itself.

Anyways I don't know mootools so can't help you there, but if your request in ending in a internal server error, you have a problem with your drupal code or your js code. So even if I knew exactly what you were doing, I couldn't tell you the problem without looking at the drupal code for your `http://myDrupalSite.com/services/json` callback.

In general, what you want to make sure is:

- You make a POST request, as drupal will cache get's and the semantic of this, is that you are posting data - the node - to the server.
- Your data should be sent as post params, this will make them end up in the PHP $_POST variable
- Your callback should validate the data and act accordingly, creating a node when the data is intact. You don't need session id's since the script will have the same session the browser has.

I've answered a similar question in detail, which was about altering a field instead of saving a node, but much of the work is still the same. You can take a look on the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670858/drupal-6-jquery-ajax-update-a-field/1672353#1672353), although this is with jQuery and not Mootools.